# Is it possible to create html Cucumber Report without Maven

Tags: maven, selenium, webdriver, cucumber, report

I'm working on Cucumber automation using selenium webdriver. I'm fairly new and have not used Maven just yet. I have not been able to generate an html report. Currently, my target remains blank.

Is it because I'm not using Maven or is it possible to create/generate without it
If YES, then how?
If NO, then whats the reason?

Comment: Tbh I'd recommend using maven for dependency management anyway. What are your current dependencies and versions, how are you running your tests, and how are you trying to generate the report?

Comment: Thanks @Marit for your suggestions. I have not really looked into generating report just yet. But in my tests i did notice that my target folder had a blank file. Upon doing some research most of the answers (almost all) I found had maven for reports. So I wasn't sure about it. Also, not doing dependency management. I will be using Jenkins to run my tests.

Comment: I'd highly recommend using Maven for your dependency management. That way you don't have to download all the jars yourself (it even takes care of transitive dependencies for you). You can check the [cucumber docs](https://docs.cucumber.io/installation/java/) for which dependencies you need.

Comment: Are we saying there is no way you can generate an .html report without maven? Could I know the reason please.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cucumber without maven, you just need to add cucumber .jar file manually. ([here you have exemple](http://www.automationtestinghub.com/cucumber-eclipse-project/))

However I recommend you to use maven or ant or gradle. It does the same thing but automatically.

Comment: Thanks Igor. I have not looked into any of these (Maven, Ant, Gradle). Hence, the question whether I can generate the report without it or not.